# Spring Cloud Netflix Hystrix Turbine not getting info from services on the same host

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, netflix, hystrix, turbine

I have followed [Spring Cloud Netflix's guide](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html) to configure Turbine. After enabling Hystrix in two microservices I have verified that /hystrix.stream endpoints generate the correct output.

Now in a hystrix dashboard project I have configured Turbine to get the aggregated results of all the services. However all I get is a succession of:

```
: ping
data: {"reportingHostsLast10Seconds":0,"name":"meta","type":"meta","timestamp":1448552456486}
```

This is my config:

**HystrixDashboard + Turbine Application:**

```
@EnableHystrixDashboard
@EnableTurbine
@SpringBootApplication
public class HystrixDashboardApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HystrixDashboardApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**HystrixDashboard + Turbine application.yml:**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: hystrix-dashboard

server:
  port: 10000

turbine:
  appConfig: random-story-microservice,storyteller-api
  instanceUrlSuffix: /hystrix.stream

logging:
  level:
    com.netflix.turbine: 'TRACE'
```

**UPDATE**

Following kreel's directions I have configured Turbine this way:

```
turbine:
  appConfig: random-story-microservice,storyteller-api
  instanceUrlSuffix: /hystrix.stream
  clusterNameExpression: new String("default")
```

It doesn't fail with an exception anymore and in the logs I see that Turbine finds the two candidate hosts/microservices:

```
[        Timer-0] c.n.t.discovery.InstanceObservable       : Retrieved hosts from InstanceDiscovery: 2
```

However only one of them is finally registered. In `InstanceObservable.run()` only one of the hosts is added because they have the same hashcode so they are considered the same when added to newState.hostsUp. The `com.netflix.turbine.discovery.Instance` hashcode is calculated based on the hostname ("myhost" in both cases), and cluster ("default"):

```
// set the current state
            for(Instance host: newList) {
                if(host.isUp()) {
                    newState.hostsUp.add(host);
                } else {
                    newState.hostsDown.add(host);
                }
            }
```

What do we have to do when the same host offers two different microservices? Only the first instance is registered in this case.

Comment: There is an enhancement that will allow turbine to this. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/pull/661

Comment: Great! Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

I think I have an answer but first, to be sure, why are you expecting "default" ?

Comment: I haven't configured any cluster in `turbine: aggregator: clusterConfig: XXXX`, thus clusterName's value is `default`

Answer (score 0):

In fact I think you are misunderstanding the doc :

```
The configuration key turbine.appConfig is a list of eureka serviceIds that turbine will use to lookup instances. The turbine stream is then used in the Hystrix dashboard using a url that looks like: http://my.turbine.sever:8080/turbine.stream?cluster=<CLUSTERNAME>; (the cluster parameter can be omitted if the name is "default"). The cluster parameter must match an entry in turbine.aggregator.clusterConfig. Values returned from eureka are uppercase, thus we expect this example to work if there is an app registered with Eureka called "customers":

turbine:
  aggregator:
    clusterConfig: CUSTOMERS
  appConfig: customers
```

In your case :

```
turbine:
  aggregator:
    clusterConfig: MY_CLUSTER
  appConfig: random-story-microservice,storyteller-api
```

So it will return "random-story-microservice,storyteller-api" in uppercase.

Comment: Thanks for anwering. You're right, I had misunderstood the documentation. However (see UPDATE 2 in the question), that way you only get info about one service at a time

Answer (score 0):

So, I think you need to apply this part :

```
The clusterName can be customized by a SPEL expression in turbine.clusterNameExpression with root an instance of InstanceInfo. The default value is appName, which means that the Eureka serviceId ends up as the cluster key (i.e. the InstanceInfo for customers has an appName of "CUSTOMERS"). A different example would be turbine.clusterNameExpression=aSGName, which would get the cluster name from the AWS ASG name. Another example:

turbine:
  aggregator:
    clusterConfig: SYSTEM,USER
  appConfig: customers,stores,ui,admin
  clusterNameExpression: metadata['cluster']

In this case, the cluster name from 4 services is pulled from their metadata map, and is expected to have values that include "SYSTEM" and "USER".

To use the "default" cluster for all apps you need a string literal expression (with single quotes):

turbine:
  appConfig: customers,stores
  clusterNameExpression: 'default'

Spring Cloud provides a spring-cloud-starter-turbine that has all the dependencies you need to get a Turbine server running. Just create a Spring Boot application and annotate it with @EnableTurbine.
```

Add this in your config : 
clusterNameExpression: 'default'

Comment: When using clusterNameExpression: 'default' I get an exception at startup: `org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'default' cannot be found on object of type 'com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo' - maybe not public?`

Comment: I'll try setting up Eureka client's metadata maps with a common name. Thank's again for your help

Comment: No i think this is sending you the aggregate info directly now. Just try to print the result of your query juste to see.